# Angular 16: Either AngularFireModule has not been provided in your AppModule (this can be done manually or implictly using provideFirebaseApp)

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

**Versions info:
@angular/fire 7.6.1
@angular/common": 16.0.0

The error I am recieving:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNVxK.png)

I was trying to implement unit testing in my angular project where I have implemented angular/fire, the code runs perfectly but while unit testing it asks for AngularFireModule (which has been deprocated in newer versions):

My authentication service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {
  Auth,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  authState,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  UserCredential,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  currentUser$ = authState(this.auth);
  constructor(private auth: Auth) {}

  signUp(email: string, password: string): Observable<UserCredential> {
    return from(createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password));
  }

  login(email: any, password: any): Observable<any> {
    return from(signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, email, password));
  }

  logout(): Observable<any> {
    return from(this.auth.signOut());
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any update? I'm trying to test an angular app with your same versions but when I try to test a component that inject a service that use authState I receive your same error.